# Prohibit indexing aliases and original paths for search engines

Tags: domain-access

For the same website two domains are used.

Would onedomain.com/node/100 be indexed by search engines for the alias onedomain.com/article/100 which is disallowed to be indexed by search engines in robots.txt? (onedomain.com/node/100 = onedomain.com/article/100)

Comment: It is different but they are connected.

Comment: There it's a question to disallow one path to be indexed. Here the question is about the path and its alias.

Comment: I see. It's a bit confusing because you have 2 similar questions that were posted next to each other on a near related topic. For the above the you want to look at something like Metatag or Global Redirect that can generate a canonical metatag (essentially telling a search engine that 2 URLs are equivocal).